# Is it correct to use UI and Model for Backbone.Marionette's Layout View?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

in Backbone.Marionette the Layout View extends the item view and therefor it has the UI elements and can handle a Model. But is it semantically, Philosophically correct to assign a model to a layout view and bind UI elements to it? or a Layout should only have regions and a template?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** I believe the Marionette philosophy is to minimize the semantics. The methods defined in Marionette.View where selected to be inherited by all Marionette views.  While all derivative Marionette views are better at what they're designed for, they are still a Marionette.View.

---

As of the creation date of this post I've been using Marionette on a daily basis on an enterprise project for over a year. I try to stay active in the community and keep abreast of edge Marionette releases.

From my experience, Marionette imposes an opinion on how to build and manipulate views, but it consciously tries to keep it's views as flexible and general as possible. To wit, see this [issue](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2268), where [`@jmeas`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727181/jmeas) (a major Marionette contributor and visionary) envisions reducing Marionette to LayoutViews and CollectionViews!

I think the best answer to your question is, if the method is natively available in your view, it's not an accident. The Marionette View inheritance structure has been heavily tested. I've yet to see a method in any derivative View that contradicts the semantics of that View.

---

**UPDATE** I think it is worhwhile to point out that there is a potentially major **caveat** to rendering a model inside a LayoutView template.

Consider this scenario. You have a LayoutView with a model, and at least one region. You also `.show()` a sub-view in a region of the LayoutView. Now, the data in the LayoutView is updated in a different view, and you want to dynamically update your LayoutView. If you ***render*** the LayoutView again, then the whole view gets discarded, *including* the sub-view that was rendered, demanding a second render of that sub-view.

In some situations this could be a significant performance hit. And there may be other issues depending on how that sub-view was originally handled in the LayoutView.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely correct to use a model in layout view. I could think of various use case cases where it might be useful:

- Showing some **dynamic** attribute which is present in a model.
- Passing the values from one view to another ans so on.
- Listening ans responding to a change in its model attributes.